# How to update primary key field using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, primary-key

I have set field called `cus_id` into primary key field which is not `AutoField`. 
I need to change pk alon to keep other relevant data for same id should be in same index instead pk alone need to be change.

if i gave request via `PATCH`/`PUT` it creates new record instead of updating `PK`

so i have gone through [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) which says,

> The primary key field is read-only. If you change the value of the primary key on an existing object and then save it, a new object will be created alongside the old one.

but i am using Django Rest Framework for my API generation.. 
I can achieve it through overriding DRF GET methods. but i want to do without overridden.
is there any `django` way to update `PK` using `DRF` without overriding get method?

**My view:**

```
class ModelViewSet(ModelCustomViewSet):
    model = Model
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    filter_fields = model._meta.get_all_field_names()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackendExt, ]
```

**Serializer:**

```
class ModelSerializer(RequiredMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        update_lookup_field = "cus_id"
```

Comment: updating `pk` isn't good practice, is it?

Comment: i know its not never done before.. but now facing scenario where i need to change. but obviously its not a good practice .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you forget about using custom field for PK and go with regular auto id. Alongside you still can use you your `cus_id`, requiring it to be non-nullable and unique. That way you can update it via a regular form with absolutely no problems.

Otherwise, you can do update it as you do, clone old instance fields contents into new one and delete old one.